# Why is JTable border cut after converting to PDF?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, graphics2d

I have this JTable with contents and I would want to print its contents but after printing and coverting it to PDF the borders on the left and top sides are missing.

Here is a sample output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yg1s.png]

Here is my printButton code below:

```
            Printable printable = new Printable() {
                @Override
                public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                    if (pageIndex == 0) {
                        int x = (int) pageFormat.getImageableX();
                        int y = (int) pageFormat.getImageableY();
                        int pageWidth = (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
                        int pageHeight = (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight();

                        // Define the border size
                        int borderSize = 72; // 1 inch = 72 points

                        // Draw the empLabel and empNameTxtField
                        String empLabelValue = empNameLabel.getText();
                        String empNameValue = empNameTextField.getText();
                        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                        graphics.drawString(empLabelValue, x + borderSize, y + 50 + borderSize);
                        graphics.drawString(empNameValue, x + 100 + borderSize, y + 50 + borderSize);

                        // Draw the table
                        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                        g2d.translate(x + borderSize , y + 70 + borderSize);

                        double tableWidth = table.getPreferredSize().getWidth();
                        double tableHeight = table.getPreferredSize().getHeight();

                        double scaleX = (pageWidth - 2 * borderSize + 210) / tableWidth;
                        double scaleY = (pageHeight - 2 * borderSize) / tableHeight;
                        double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

                        g2d.scale(scale, scale);

                        table.getTableHeader().print(g2d);
                        g2d.translate(0, table.getTableHeader().getHeight());
                        table.print(g2d);

                        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
                    } else {
                        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                    }
                }
            };
```

I have tried re-adjusting the size of the scale and rescaling the printable area but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas in solving this problem is a very big help thank yoou!